# Reading multiple inputs in python

Tags: python

How to take 3 inputs separated by a space in python, equivalent to `scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&n);` in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a, b, n = map(int, input('enter three values: ').split())
```

Example

```
enter three values: 3 5 6

>>> a
3
>>> b
5
>>> n
6
```

This solution is for Python 3.x In Python 2.x replace `input` with `raw_input`.

Answer (score 2):

Use **raw_input()** to get values from keyboard.

1. Ask User to enter values from the keyboard by `raw_input()`
2. Split user enters values by space.
3. Use type casting to convert string to integer.

Demo:

```
>>> a = raw_input("Enter three number separated by space:")
Enter three number separated by space:1 3 2
>>> print a
1 3 2
>>> print type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> a1 = a.split()
>>> a1
['1', '3', '2']
>>> int(a1[0])
1
>>>
```

---

**Exception Handling:**

Best practise to handle exception during Type Casting because User might enter alpha values also.

Demo:

```
>>> try:
...    a = int(raw_input("Enter digit:"))
... except ValueError:
...    print "Enter only digit."
...    a = 0
... 
Enter digit:e
Enter only digit.
```

**Note:**
Use `input()` for `Python 3.x` and `raw_input()` for `Python 2.x`

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#simulating-scanf) you can use regular expression to parse the string as in `scanf`.

```
input_string = raw_input()
import re
m = re.search("([-+]?\d+) ([-+]?\d+) ([-+]?\d+)", input_string)
if m is None:
   raise ValueError("input not valid %s" % input_string)
input_numbers = map(int, input_string_splitted)
```